# Лайки и избранное

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Во вью у меня такой блок:

```
<span class="col-md-4"><a href="#" title="Мне нравится"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
<span class="col-md-4"><a href="#" title="Нажмите, чтобы добавить в избранное (повторно, чтобы отменить)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></span>
```

Модель Like и Favourite содержит 2 столбца (string UserId, int MovieId).

Как мне реализовать, чтобы при первом нажатии на кнопку "Лайк" или "Избранное" в БД записались данные, при этом картинка в этот же момент должна поменяться на "лайкнуто" или "в избранном". При повторном нажатии на кнопку, необходимо, чтобы данные удалились и картинка опять вернулась? Попробовал через Ajax, но не получилось. Что должно возвращаться в методе в контроллере?

```
public ActionResult Like(int id)
        {
            var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Likes.Add(new Like { UserId = userId, MovieId = id });
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView();
        }
```

Comment: а вам только количество лайков надо показать или сами лайки?

Comment: мне надо, чтобы пользователь мог поставить лайк фильму и его удалить, так же и в избранное. Потом список избранного вывести ему. Подсчитывать ничего не надо.

Comment: то есть количество лайков и кто лайкнул вам выводить не надо? Обычно количество выводится, в противном случае зачем вообще лайки нужны?

Comment: в моем случае задание звучит так: Пользователь должен иметь возможность отметить фильм, который ему понравился и добавить его в избранное.

Comment: а вы видели где-нибудь что бы были лайки но не выводилось их количество? Просто я сейчас могу вам ответить, а потом будете переделывать, так как это не особенно логично... Теже фэйсбук, контакт, и другие сети. Везде выводится количество лайков.

Comment: Согласен, без вывода кол-ва не видел нигде... в класс Movie добавлю свойство int TotalLikes, будем записывать в него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

Ваше действие контроллера должна возвращать частичную вьюшку в которую уже входит ссылка для убрать лайк / добавить лайк в зависимости от того есть ли уже лайк или нет. И сразу же возвращать количество лайков. При этом обработку ссылки сделать через ненавязчивый ajax.

То есть у вас будет два действия контроллера `AddLike`, `RemoveLike` и оба возвращать одну и туже частичную вьюшку с ссылкой и количеством лайков.

Answer (score 1):

Вью:

```
@{
var userId = Session["ID"];
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"><span>(@b.TotalLikes)</span></i>
}
else if (b.Likes.Any(a => a.UserId == userId && a.MovieId == b.Id))
{
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="unlike" data-id="@b.Id"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart text-danger"><span>(@b.TotalLikes)</span></i></a>
}
else
{
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="like" data-id="@b.Id"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty"><span>(@b.TotalLikes)</span></i></a>
}
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public string LikeThis(int id)
{
    var movie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["Username"] != null)
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == username);
        movie.TotalLikes++;
        if (user != null)
        {
            var like = new Like
            {
                MovieId = id,
                UserId = user.Id
            };
            db.Likes.Add(like);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return movie.TotalLikes.ToString();
}

public string UnlikeThis(int id)
{
    var movie = db.Movies.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || Session["Username"] != null)
    {
        var username = User.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == username);
        movie.TotalLikes--;
        var like = db.Likes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.MovieId == id && a.UserId == user.Id);
        if (like != null)
        {
            db.Likes.Remove(like);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return movie.TotalLikes.ToString();
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //LIKE
        $(document).on("click", "a.like", function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var link = "/Home/LikeThis/" + id;
            var a = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: link,
                success: function (result) {
                    a.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart text-danger"></span> (' + result + ')').removeClass("like").addClass("unlike");
                }
            });
        });
        //UNLIKE
        $(document).on("click","a.unlike",function () {
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var link = "/Home/UnlikeThis/" + id;
            var a = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: link,
                success: function (result) {
                    a.html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart text-danger"></span> (' + result + ')');
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Но не работает, т.к. не могу вытащить стринговое Id юзера проверить хотябы.

Comment: `var userId = Session["ID"];` - это откуда взялось, и как оно соотносится с `Session["Username"]` и `User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: да, суть кода правильная! только осталось научиться получать Id пользователя.

Comment: да, в этом и загвоздка пока. Чтобы понять есть ли лайк в таблице, мне надо просмотреть её на наличие UserId и MovieId, но User.Identity возвращает только имя и было бы совсем неправильно в каждой итерации цикла foreach запрашивать эту информацию из БД. А попытавшись её получить в начале вьюшки у меня вылетела ошибка, возможно, я просто не указал, что вытаскивать надо при залогиненном пользователе. Попробую.

Comment: дописал в начало вьюхи код     var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var username = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        if (username != null)
        {
            ViewBag.UserId = username.Id;
        }
    }

Comment: Во! Всё верно! только обычно это делают не во вьюшке, а в действии контроллера. а во вьюшку уже залогиненого пользователя передавать.

Comment: Заработало!!! Спасибо всем, вот только у меня разметка ползти начала, но это уже мои косяки, буду искать. Избранное я так понимаю делается по такому же принципу?

Comment: пока туда-сюда гонял, сломал) лайки в минус идут))

Comment: в общем смысл такой, если я лайкнул и потом тутже убрал лайк, то второй раз лайкнуть мне не дает и каунтер уходит в минус, как только перезагружу страницу, то все снова работает. В чем может быть причина? код больше не менял. Это на одном конкретном фильме. Другие по разу могу лайкнуть.